# Postgresql - How to get an array of key values from a jsonb array of objects

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to convert a `jsonb` array of objects to an array with only the values from a specific key without using unnest?

Another way to ask this is, in PSQL can you pick a value by key name from an array of objects and map it into an array?

This shows the format of the data to convert:

```
SELECT t.column1 AS data FROM (VALUES
        ('[{"a": 1, "b": 5 },{"a": 2, "b": 6 },{"a": 3, "b": 7 },{"a": 4, "b": 8 }]'::jsonb),
        ('[{"a": 2, "b": 5 },{"a": 4, "b": 6 },{"a": 5, "b": 7 },{"a": 6, "b": 8 }]'::jsonb),
        ('[{"a": 7, "b": 5 },{"a": 8, "b": 6 },{"a": 9, "b": 7 },{"a": 10, "b": 8 }]'::jsonb)
    ) t;

Result

data
----------------------
[{"a": 1, "b": 5}, {"a": 2, "b": 6}, {"a": 3, "b": 7}, {"a": 4, "b": 8}]
[{"a": 2, "b": 5}, {"a": 4, "b": 6}, {"a": 5, "b": 7}, {"a": 6, "b": 8}]
[{"a": 7, "b": 5}, {"a": 8, "b": 6}, {"a": 9, "b": 7}, {"a": 10, "b": 8}]
```

This is the required result where data from the "a" key has been mapped into the array

```
data
---------------------
[1,2,3,4]
[2,4,5,6]
[7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the keyvalue method of [jsonpath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH).

```
with t as (VALUES
        ('[{"a": 1, "b": 5 },{"a": 2, "b": 6 },{"a": 3, "b": 7 },{"a": 4, "b": 8 }]'::jsonb),
        ('[{"a": 2, "b": 5 },{"a": 4, "b": 6 },{"a": 5, "b": 7 },{"a": 6, "b": 8 }]'::jsonb),
        ('[{"a": 7, "b": 5 },{"a": 8, "b": 6 },{"a": 9, "b": 7 },{"a": 10, "b": 8 }]'::jsonb)
    ) 
select jsonb_path_query_array(column1, '$.keyvalue()?(@.key=="a").value ') from t;
```